# Accordion open and close text doesn't change back

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have an accordion. Works great, however I've run into to one issue. When the accordion is closed, it reads "Expand", when it's expanded, it reads "Hide". When you click to hide, it doesn't change back to expand. You'll find the code I'm using below.

EDIT: I'm using Bootstrap 3 Collapse: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

JS:

```
$('.is-toggle').click(function() {
    if($(this).next('.sec-collapse').hasClass('collapse')) {
        $(this).text('Expand');
    } else {
        $(this).text('Hide');
    }
});
```

Comment: posted you related HTML code too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to add or remove the class `.collapse`, in order to trigger the `.text()` logic. It's hard to say without seeing the HTML, but something like:

```
$('.is-toggle').click(function() {
    if($(this).next('.sec-collapse').hasClass('collapse')) {
        $(this).text('Expand');
        $(this).removeClass('collapse');
    } else {
        $(this).text('Hide');
        $(this).addClass('collapse');
    }
});
```

Comment: Instead of .collapse, you may need to test for a class of your creation that's not related to the bootstrap foundation, and then add or remove that to toggle your text logic. Same principal would apply.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks @TaiwoOster, appreciate the feedback :)